# Как отправлять фото по file_id pyTelegramBotAPI

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text", "contact", "photo", "voice"])
def mess(message):
admin_id = 231... # случайный написал здесь
    if message.voice:
        bot.send_voice(admin_id, message.voice.file_id, f"Имя = {mess.chat.first_name}\n"
                                                     f"user_name = {mess.chat.username}")
    elif message.photo:
        bot.send_photo(admin_id, message.photo.file_id)
```

Оставленные голосовые сообщения в чате бота, отправляются на указанный id, то есть в другой телеграм аккаунт, а фото нет.

И так тоже не работает (хотя понимаю, что это не должно что-то поменять):

```
elif message.photo:
    bot.send_photo(chat_id=231..., photo=message.photo.file_id)
```

Объекте .photo, содержит:
`{'file_id': '', 'file_unique_id': '', 'width': , 'height': , 'file_size':}`

Вот конкретное фото, которое выберу, с помощью функции open, могу отправить admin_id, а то что пользователь отправил в чат бот, - нет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Фото нужно отправлять так. Ибо вы берете оригинальный размер фото

```
bot.send_photo(chat_id=..., photo=message.photo[-1].file_id)
```

Comment: Все работает. А то я сидел 2 дня, и не мог понять в чем дело. А все дело в file_size [-1]. 
То есть в объекте .photo мы извлекли последний элемент 'file_size' + применили file_id. Правильно понимаю?

Comment: Угу, все так....